# Make a 512 UDP bytes DNS request

Tags: python, dns, size

I have a question. I have read various RFCs and so many info on internet.
I read that DNS through UDP has a 512 bytes limit. I want to write a python program that use this max limit to create a well generated DNS request. It is very important to use UDP and not the TCP DNS implementation.
I have tried using public libraries but they did not use the 512 bytes that can be use like the RFC says.

It is very important too, to use the ~ 512 bytes to sent so much data in a single request.

Thank you for your help!

Let's make it happens!! ;)

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 512 bytes limit is for a dns **message**, not specifically for a request, and the limitation is only valid for **responses**, which can contain Resource Records.

For a **request** you are limited to the 253 bytes of the domain name.

You might be able to manually create a query containing Resource Records, but it will probably be dropped by your local dns server.

Comment: Incorrect, you can have several questions in the query (how it will be handled is a difficult question, typically depending on the server), and you can have the additional section (used, for instance, by EDNS). So, it is perfectly possible to have a query of 512 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't exactly force 512 byte limit or UDP transport on your DNS requests. What [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) exactly says about transports (section 4.2) is that `datagrams are preferred for queries due to their lower overhead and better performance`.

That is to say that UDP is **preffered** as more lightweight transport whenever applicable, which is mostly a matter of request size. Rule of thumb would be for requests less then 512 bytes long to be transported over UDP, and for more then 512 bytes long over TCP. (There are exceptions though, like `zone refresh activities` mentioned in section 4.2.)

Most popular Python DNS libraries (like [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)) handle this correctly when using high-level querying. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'd rephrase that: IF the application/script you are writing is intended to be production quality and in the hands of end users, THEN ou shouldn't exactly force 512 byte limit or UDP transport on your DNS requests.  On the other hand, you do not say why you want this (your goal), and maybe you are doing some edge/destructive QA testing in which case your question is perfectly valid.